# Manifest Merger failed for minSDKVersion

Tags: java, android, sdk, manifest, android-support-library

With the following gradle script, I was wondering how to change the minSdkVersion from 7 to 3 (just so my app could run on more devices) without getting the error at the bottom of this post:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dpark.cellular_automata"
        minSdkVersion 3
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

... And then I would get the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 3 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1] C:\Users\Dave\AndroidStudioProjects\Cellular_Automata\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

... That said, is it even possible to lower my minimum SDK to 3 (version 1.5, Cupcake) if I wanted to publish my app with Google Play? And also, in case you're wondering, I also downloaded the Android Support Library in the SDK manager as follows, and yet it still doesn't work:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is telling you that one of your libraries (in this case, AppCompat) only supports back to SDK version 7. Since that library cannot support anything lower than 7 and you use that library, you can't support anything lower than 7.

Your options are either:

- Remove AppCompat
- Support a minimum of API level 7. Note that [SDK version 8 currently has less than 0.1%](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of the market share globally, and all versions less than 8 have a combined total of 1%. It probably isn't worth your time.

> That said, is it even possible to lower my minimum SDK to 3 (version 1.5, Cupcake) if I wanted to publish my app with Google Play?

Absolutely. You could upload an Android app supporting API level 1 if you really wanted to.

> And also, in case you're wondering, I also downloaded the Android Support Library in the SDK manager as follows, and yet it still doesn't work:

The support library v4 only supports back to API level 4, so I'm not sure how that would help with supporting API level 3.